# Before and after bind events in wpf controls

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my situation: I have some datagrid controls, that allows users to sort by some columns. This is ok.
In some situations I need to reload the data. After reloading, datagrid loses the sort information.

So I thought to create my own datagrid that stores sorting information before binding and restore after binding.

Is there any events or something else that does that ?

Comment: What controls do you use in your Grid, are those custom controls? And why do you need to reload the collection? Is it some sort of `Refresh`?

Comment: CollectionViewSource & sort informations inside ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation some time ago. Here is my solution:

In xaml set NotifyOnTargetUpdated of DataGrid binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MySourceData, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
```

and set the TargetUpdated event of this DataGrid:

```
TargetUpdated="MyGrid_TargetUpdated"
```

You can create your own DataGrid control that stores and restores sort information in the TargetUpdated event handler.